# Where should I perform (groups/roles equivalent) in B2C with OIDC and OAuth / API access?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps, identity-experience-framework

I'm looking at the [B2C API demos](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi), and API [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens) and I'm unable to determine the preferred method for managing authorization.

Azure AD supports assigning AD Users/Groups to apps, and also roles. Seemingly B2C doesn't support this. (I experimented by using AAD tasks against a B2C tenant. Hopefully I did it correctly)

Given that a singular B2C tenant will offer web sign in, and most likely API access as well, what is the benefit of creating more than one scope as exhibited in the TodoList:TodoListScope.

- Can I conditionally add additional scopes? Using B2C or store it in the graph/application somewhere?

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C

- Or more abstractly, how should I perform authorization to the many different APIs (and apps) when an id_token is exchanged for an access_token?

Perhaps API Management will give me ideas on how to perform RBAC or other permissioning. Added them as a tag as well

Comment: What do you mean by "add additional scopes"? Are the additional scopes from other resources? Saying that, you have multiple Web API registration apps?

Comment: @AllenWu Hello Allen, the issue relates to "what is the benefit of having more than one scope between a B2C application and its API if I can't assign different scopes to different users". I'm using scopes for Authorization.  The problem repeats in many different scenarios {Access to some API apps not others, etc). I think the issue relates to the Client Credential Flow and the beta app proxy... and bringing AAD features to B2C. I'm going to bespoke a solution for a medium sized customer using extension attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an RBAC [Github sample here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples) that requires you to use [work accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview) which are called "B2C Users" in the portal below.

Users created this way, can be added to groups located within Azure Active Directory (by script).  Testing still in progress

[image]